# How do you say "He was like I dunno" in German?

Tags: translation, english-to-german

How do you say "He was like I dunno" in German colloquially and formally? Can I use *wie* or *also*?

> Did you tell him that you're in love with him?
> Yes, I did and he was like I don't know.
>
> Hast du ihn gefragt, ob er in dich verliebt ist?
>
> Ja, er war wie/also *ich weiß nicht*.

Comment: I see that the question initially was formatted as `' he was like i dunno'` . Please notice that this `'` with  a space thereafter is causing trouble in most of your questions. Kindly write what you want to quote `"like this"`.

Comment: This is about the *like*, isn’t it? I thought it would be about the *I dunno* part … ^^'

Comment: Please control your punctation. There are different interpretations of your question. *He was like: "I don*t know"* or *He was like - I don*t know.* Is the *I don't know* in the voice of the third person or the second?

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Ich würde schreiben:

> Er war wie, also, ich weiß nicht.

This implies that the speaker wants to say something, but mid-sentence, he's unsure about what to say.

Comment: Just to make this sure: This definitly is colloquial.

Comment: Ist Dir die englische Wendung „he was like“, die Du hier zu übersetzen versuchst, geläufig?

Comment: Ich glaube schon, aber jetzt bin ich mir nicht mehr so sicher... Ich denke, es bedeutet in etwa "Es war seine Art...", "Er war nun einmal so.".

Comment: "He was like" ist eine umgangssprachliche Art, wörtliche Rede einzuleiten. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Like#As_a_colloquial_quotative Ich bin mir aber nicht sicher, ob das hier gemeint ist.

Comment: Oh, diese Bedeutung war mir unbekannt. Zum Verständnis wäre es gut, wenn die Satzzeichen in der Frage korrekt platziert würden.

Comment: I agree with your last sentence... the "also" used here is a filler to by time and rearrange grammar. But this doesn't answer the question because  it is not what happens in the English original where the pattern "Someone was like + direct speech" is so fixed it can even be considered grammaticalized.

Comment: @Emanuel: Even without quotation marks?

Comment: @PMF... I think this is basically limited to spoken language but I think English accepts it just like this.. in chats and so on... I was like duuuuuh.   I doubt people would walk the extra mile and add :"" just to get the punctuation right :)

Answer (score 21):

The closest equivalent to the English direct speech marker "like" is definitely "so".

> Ich so, "sind wir zusammen?", und er so, "weiß nich'"

This is how it's done on the school yard all day long.